# pausing and playing events changes CSS in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I would like to know how to change the CSS of the audio element when its playing and then once again when it is paused.

```
//when playing
$("audio#musicbar").on('play',function(){
     $().css ({
         'box-shadow':'1px 0px 20px lime'
     });
});

//When paused
$(#musicbar").on('pause',function(){
     $().css ({
         'box-shadow':'1px 0px 20px green'
     });
});
```

I wrote this but it doesnt work, i am just a hobbiest and dont know very much about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#musicbar').click(function() {
   if (this.paused == false) {
      this.pause();
      $(this).css ({
          'box-shadow':'1px 0px 20px green'
      });
   }
   else {
     this.play();
     $(this).css ({
     'box-shadow':'1px 0px 20px lime'
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: didnt work for me, did you test this code? if so then maybe i have something else wrong in my document.